# Convert all csv files from encodeing ansi to utf8 using python

Tags: python, csv, utf-8

I have python code as below:

```
import os
from os import listdir

def find_csv_filenames( path_to_dir, suffix=".csv" ):
    filenames = listdir(path_to_dir)
    return [ filename for filename in filenames if filename.endswith( suffix ) ]
    #always got the error this below code
filenames = find_csv_filenames('C:\casperjs\project\teleservices\csv')
for name in filenames:
    print name
```

I meet the error :

```
filenames = find_csv_filenames('C:\casperjs\project\teleservices\csv')
Error message: `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`
```

What I need : I want to read all csv files and convert it from encoding ansi to utf8 but the code above is only read path of each csv files. I don't know what's wrong with it?

Comment: Format your code and post full error message, please.

Comment: ok thanks now I already show you the error message.

Comment: You should fix [indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Indentation) at first.

Comment: Does the error gone after formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below will convert each line in ascii-file:

```
import os
from os import listdir

def find_csv_filenames(path_to_dir, suffix=".csv" ):
    path_to_dir = os.path.normpath(path_to_dir)
    filenames = listdir(path_to_dir)
    #Check *csv directory
    fp = lambda f: not os.path.isdir(path_to_dir+"/"+f) and f.endswith(suffix)
    return [path_to_dir+"/"+fname for fname in filenames if fp(fname)]

def convert_files(files, ascii, to="utf-8"):
    for name in files:
        print "Convert {0} from {1} to {2}".format(name, ascii, to)
        with open(name) as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                pass
                print unicode(line, "cp866").encode("utf-8")    

csv_files = find_csv_filenames('/path/to/csv/dir', ".csv")
convert_files(csv_files, "cp866") #cp866 is my ascii coding. Replace with your coding.
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

If you need a string, say it is stored as *s*, that you want to encode as a specific format, you use s.encode()

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just listing csv files. It doesn't do anything with it. If you need to read it, you can use the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module. If you need to manage encoding, you can do something like this:

```
import csv, codecs
def safe_csv_reader(the_file, encoding, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
    csv_reader = csv.reader(the_file, dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        yield [codecs.decode(cell, encoding) for cell in row]

reader = safe_csv_reader(csv_file, "utf-8", delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    print row
```